# Ubuntu showing wrong maximum battery percentage

Tags: battery, mac, macbook-pro

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu on an old 2007 MacBook Pro and it is reporting the wrong battery percentage.
Can someone show me how I can tweak the upower to show the right percentage.

[image]

Comment: What make you think it is wrong ?

Comment: Proof would be to get a new battery and see if that one shows 100% or not. If it does this one is broken.

Answer (score 1):

As `Soren A` said in the comments, I don't believe that there is anything wrong. Batteries simply degrade over time and are capable of holding less and less. The only way to fix it is by getting a new battery.

Comment: This is indeed a new one. I dont get the percentrages, how can 58,4 Wh chared out of maximum 58,4 Wh only be 70%? Even 58,4Wh out of 60,5 Wh would be 96%.